# Include Gem in Ruby Script Run in Alfred Workflow

Tags: ruby, rubygems, alfred, sonos

I'm trying to create an Alfred workflow to change the volume with hotkeys through Alfred.

A working gem to control Sonos is here:https://github.com/soffes/sonos

The problem is: including the gem as part of a script just plain doesn't work. When I run the workflow nothing happens. I've attached a screenshot of the Alfred screenshot I'm talking about.

I've tried other Ruby scripts and they run just fine. But anything that requires a gem doesn't work.

I've also tried downloading the gem and just requiring the absolute path, but no luck there, either.

[image: Alfred screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The `sonos` gem uses the `savon` gem for SOAP communication with the Sonos api. `Savon` was logging to `stdout` and that was preventing Alfred workflows from working (they depend on `stdout` to communicate). [My fork of the sonos gem](http://github.com/barelyknown/sonos) disables the logging and can be used in your Alfred workflow.

```
require '/path/to/sonos'

Sonos.savon_config = { log: false }

speaker = Sonos::System.new.speakers.first

puts case "{query}"
  when "play" then speaker.play and "Playing"
  when "pause" then speaker.pause and "Paused"
  when "up" then speaker.volume += 5 and "Turned up"
  when "down" then speaker.volume -= 5 and "Turned down"
  when "next" then speaker.next and "Next"
  else "Unknown command"
end
```

Comment: And the language dropdown in Alfred is set to bash or Ruby?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mce4vmc6qdt4grf/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-02%20at%2010.48.49%20AM.png

Comment: If you use system ruby, then you can select ruby from the drop down in the Alfred workflow.